# Robot Framework -SSHLibrary - File Should Exist

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework, functional-testing, robotframework-sshlibrary

I am currently developing test case in Robot Framework with Eclipse and RED plugin to automate a test case on Linux VM.
The code for one of the keyword goes like this

```
**Check Auth Certificate** 
    [Documentation]    To Check Whether the Authentication certificate is present or not   
    Log    *** Needs to be implemented ***
    Send Command    pwd
    Send Command    cd /root/.ssh/
    Send Command    pwd
    ${fileExist}    File Should Exist    'mqtt-server.crt'
```

***Send Command*** is a custom keyword to execute the commands with Write & Read Keywords and logs the result.
Problem is - there is a file (mqtt-server.crt) present in this location - /root/.ssh/. From the console output, am able to validate that the control has reached within the required folder.
However, when the keyword from SSHLibrary- **File Should Exist** is executed, it **Fails**.
I want to validate if the mentioned file is present in the folder, and if it is present, it needs to be deleted.
The output in the console is

```
20210623 00:23:47.024 : INFO : *** Needs to be implemented ***
20210623 00:23:47.118 : INFO : pwd
20210623 00:23:48.120 : INFO : /root
[root@<host> ~]#
20210623 00:23:48.121 : INFO : Response After :: pwd - -> /root
[root@<host> ~]# 
20210623 00:23:48.226 : INFO : cd /root/.ssh/
20210623 00:23:49.227 : INFO : [root@<host> .ssh]#
20210623 00:23:49.227 : INFO : ${resultCommand} = [root@<host> .ssh]# 
20210623 00:23:49.228 : INFO : Response After :: cd /root/.ssh/ - -> [root@<host> .ssh]# 
20210623 00:23:49.320 : INFO : pwd
20210623 00:23:50.321 : INFO : /root/.ssh
20210623 00:23:50.321 : INFO : ${resultCommand} = /root/.ssh
20210623 00:23:50.408 : INFO : ls
20210623 00:23:50.408 : INFO : ${responseCommand} = ls
20210623 00:23:52.411 : INFO : known_hosts  mqtt-server.crt
20210623 00:23:52.411 : INFO : ${resultCommand} = known_hosts  mqtt-server.crt
[root@<host> .ssh]# 
20210623 00:23:52.413 : INFO : Response After :: ls - -> known_hosts  mqtt-server.crt
[root@<host> .ssh]# 
20210623 00:23:52.413 : INFO : ${listOfFiles} = None
**20210623 00:23:52.415 : DEBUG : [chan 1] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
20210623 00:23:52.529 : INFO : [chan 1] Opened sftp connection (server version 3)
20210623 00:23:52.529 : DEBUG : [chan 1] normalize(b'.')
20210623 00:23:52.570 : DEBUG : [chan 1] stat(b'mqtt-server.crt')
20210623 00:23:52.603 : FAIL : File 'mqtt-server.crt' does not exist.
20210623 00:23:52.604 : DEBUG : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\SSHLibrary\library.py", line 1809, in file_should_exist
    raise AssertionError("File '%s' does not exist." % path)**
Ending test: Demo-Telemetry.TestCases.ConnectToJumpServer.First Jump
```

Can you please let me know, what needs to be changed to make this working or how this can be fixed .

Comment: Have figured out the way based on a comment from another thread. Used the following code to validate if the file is present or not


`${output}    Send Command And Return    ls
    ${match}    ${value}    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Should Contain    ${output}    ${certificateName}
    ${RETURNVALUE}    Set Variable If    '${match}' == 'PASS'    ${True}    ${False}
    Log    Final Ouput-> ${RETURNVALUE}
    Run Keyword IF    '${RETURNVALUE}' == 'True'    Run Keyword    Certificate is present    ELSE    Run Keyword    Certificate is missing`

Answer (score 2):

use absolute path in "File Should Exist" keyword. Or use "Move Directory" keyword. I dont think that if you change directory in your custom keyword, that this directory changes for the OperatingSystem library.

```
${fileExist}    File Should Exist    /root/.ssh/mqtt-server.crt
```

Comment: This. The log shows `File Should Exist` opens a new session, not reusing the previous one, and in doing so the cwd is the user's home dir _(most probably, depends on the sshd config)_.

Comment: @Jiri Janous - Tried using the absolute path, but still the same error no change in the console output

Comment: have a look at the documentation https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Introduction. Perhaps the backslash is also a problem. Also i dont think you need quotes, i will change this in the answer.